# RPi not booting in NOOBS or wheezy

Tags: boot, raspbian-wheezy, noobs

I recently got my own Raspberry Pi (2 B V1.1)
I have got an 8 GB micro SD for it.
I used the standard procedure to put Wheezy on it.
It shows the splash screen, and the console-output for about 3 seconds.
The last thing I can see is:

```
[2.702751] Freeing unused kernel memory: 384K (80754000 - 807b4000)
```

then it all restarts.

I also tried NOOBS.
It just shows the splash screen for a second.
Then a just blue screen for two seconds.
(repeat)

What is broken?

Comment: Could be a few things without more info. Have you tried a different SD card, also how is your PI setup (so peripherals, power supply etc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, after some experimenting with a friends pi I've found out that it was a faulty power cable